# PySpark Incremental Count on Condition

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Given a Spark dataframe with the following columns I am trying to construct an incremental/running count for each `id`  based on when the contents of the `event` column evaluate to `True`.

```
spark.createDataFrame([
    ('2018-01-01', 'A', False),
    ('2018-01-02', 'A', False),
    ('2018-01-03', 'A', True),
    ('2018-01-04', 'A', False),
    ('2018-01-05', 'A', True),
    ('2018-01-06', 'A', False),
    ('2018-01-01', 'B', False),
    ('2018-01-02', 'B', True),
    ('2018-01-03', 'B', False),
], ['date', 'id', 'event']).show()

+----------+---+-----+
|      date| id|event|
+----------+---+-----+
|2018-01-01|  A|false|
|2018-01-02|  A|false|
|2018-01-03|  A| true|
|2018-01-04|  A|false|
|2018-01-05|  A| true|
|2018-01-06|  A|false|
|2018-01-01|  B|false|
|2018-01-02|  B| true|
|2018-01-03|  B|false|
+----------+---+-----+
```

Here a new column called `results` would be created that contained the incremental count.

```
+----------+---+-----+------+
|      date| id|event|result|
+----------+---+-----+------+
|2018-01-01|  A|false|     0|
|2018-01-02|  A|false|     0|
|2018-01-03|  A| true|     1|
|2018-01-04|  A|false|     1|
|2018-01-05|  A| true|     2|
|2018-01-06|  A|false|     2|
|2018-01-01|  B|false|     0|
|2018-01-02|  B| true|     1|
|2018-01-03|  B|false|     1|
+----------+---+-----+------+
```

I've tried using window functions but am stumped at this point.  Ideally, the solution would increment the count row-wise without and group by or aggregation functions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sum` function, casting your `event` as an int:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = df.withColumn('result', f.sum(f.col('event').cast('int')).over((Window.partitionBy('id').orderBy('date'))))
df.sort('id', 'date').show()
# +----------+---+-----+------+
# |      date| id|event|result|
# +----------+---+-----+------+
# |2018-01-01|  A|false|     0|
# |2018-01-02|  A|false|     0|
# |2018-01-03|  A| true|     1|
# |2018-01-04|  A|false|     1|
# |2018-01-05|  A| true|     2|
# |2018-01-06|  A|false|     2|
# |2018-01-01|  B|false|     0|
# |2018-01-02|  B| true|     1|
# |2018-01-03|  B|false|     1|
# +----------+---+-----+------+
```